# How to Draw a Graph in Java

Tags: java, csv, graph, plot

I'm currently trying to think of a way to plot a graph in Java.

The basic way my program is meant to work is it finds a users .csv file and in there will be some sort of habit and the date. So like drove 5 miles on 24.10.13.

So I need to be able to extract the 5 and the 24.10.13 and take those as my Y and X co-ordinates respectively as other things are measured against date and it makes sense to have that as the X value.

So is there a library I can import or a Function I'm not aware of and could you give a simple example on how to use it?

NOTE - I've done my GUI in JavaFX as I'm not that great in JFrame and I know nothing of Swing

Comment: Try taking a look at [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/) and you may need to take a look at [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: What is the target (media)? A document? A web/desktop application? 
What level of interactivity is required?

Comment: +See: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+Draw+a+Graph+in+Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX has built-in charts. You may check [it out](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/chart-overview.htm#CJAHHJCB). That way, you won't need any external libraries.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) to plot your data? You can see some samples [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html). JGraph seems to be geared towards visualizing graphs, not for plotting functions.